# Compare two delimited files with first column

Tags: bash, join

File1

```
james:hello
richard:hello2
johnson:hello3
jam3es:hello
ja1mes:hello
```

File2

```
james:hello
ja1mes:hello
johnson:hello3
```

Expected output

```
richard:hello2
jam3es:hello
```

I have these 2 files, I'm trying to compare first column aka the name(s) with the other file name(s) and print out unique line(s) from File1.

Comment: @Quasímodo I would like to use join for this, both files are sorted by the first column

Comment: How would you get that output? What's the pattern?

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to get unique lines from the files, or only unique names,
so if the part after the colon was different, should it show up?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

The files don't appear to be sorted on the first column in any locale that I can imagine, but if you do sort them then you can trivially use `join` with the `-v` option ex.

```
$ join -t ':' -v 1 <(sort -t ':' file1) <(sort -t ':' file2)
jam3es:hello
richard:hello2
```

If you really need output in the order given, then you can pipe the results to another `sort` command.

Answer (score 1):

awk gives a nice concise solution

```bsh
awk -F: '
    NR == FNR {name[$1]; next}
    !($1 in name)
' file2 file1
```

outputs

```
richard:hello2
jam3es:hello
```

---

The sample input files show that the whole lines are duplicated. If that's actually the case, the `comm` utility is handy:

```bsh
comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

outputs the lines that only appear in file 1 (option `-2` suppresses lines that only appear in file 2, and `-3` suppresses common lines)

```
jam3es:hello
richard:hello2
```